# Why is the noise gain these opamps 500? I feel it should be 250

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, bode-plot, cutoff-frequency, gain-bandwidth-product

I wanted to check the bandwidth of the first stage of an instrumentation amplifier configuration and this is the circuit:
[image]

Since, the noise gain of an opamp is (1+Rf/R1), for each of the op-amps the noise gain should be 250. The GBW of the opamps is 1MHz. This should give us a -3dB bandwidth for each of the opamps as 1MHz/250 ~ 4000Hz.

However, on simulation, I get the bandwidth as ~2KHz indicating a gain of 500. I don't get why. Yes the overall gain of first stage is 500, however, for the individual signals it should have been 250. Please tell me what I am missing here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a gain of 500 because R5 can be regarded as two 10 ohm resistors in series AND, due to the balanced signal you are applying, that resistive centre point is naturally at signal 0 volts hence, the gain of the amplifier is the double of R6/R5 or, double of R7/R5.

Comment: Why is the resistive centre point at 0V? The signal that I am applying is 5V common mode + 10mV differential. So at one of the terminals the value is 5+Vd, and at the other terminal it is 5+(0.01-Vd).

Comment: I'm talking about the balanced signal and not the DC offset. The balanced signal will produce 0 volts AC at the common point. The fact that it is raised to +5 volts is unimportant because, the +5 volts doesn't get amplified.

Comment: I am not able to understand why AC signal matters here?

Comment: It's the AC signal that gets amplified and not the common-bias voltage.

Comment: True but my differential signal (signal to be amplified) is DC as well, and I don't get how that could be 0 at that point. It could be anything between 0 and 5mV

Comment: If your differential DC signal level is +x mV and -x mV, at the centre-point of the two resistors I invented is.... exactly 0 volts DC

Comment: @needbrainscratched have you downvoted my answer?

Comment: @needbrainscratched Gain of each side is 1 + (2Rf/R1)

Comment: @Andyaka no but I didn't upvote it either as I am waiting to hear other possible answers as well

Comment: @James But noise gain should remain 1+(Rf/R1) regardless of configuration

Comment: @needbrainscratched upvoting doesn't prevent other answers; in fact it encourages other folk to make an answer. Accepting the answer will discourage others from making an answer so you shouldn't do that until some time has passed.

Comment: @needbrainscratched Noise gain does still equal 1 +(Rf/R1) but R1 is equal to R5/2. Therefore Noise Gain = 1 + (Rf/(R5/2)) = 1 + (2Rf/R5) = (1 +  Rf/R1). Sorry if I confused the issue by putting in my first comment that Gain = 1 + (2Rf/R1) when perhaps I should have stated that Gain = 1 + (2R6/R5) or 1 + (2R7/R5) and not confused R5 with R1 where R1 is the resistance used in the Noise Gain equation and R1 is equal to R5/2.